# Installing lxml for an specific version of python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

My Mac (as all Macs) has installed a default version of python, but I installed python 2.7 manually. The issue is that now when I install lxml, I believe that my py2.7 version is not getting it, insttead it was installed for the preinstalled python, since it throws a "no module named lxml" error even after installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is just a python script, you can run `/some/other/python $(which pip) install lxml`

Comment: how can I change the path variable for python?

Comment: nvm, i found out how. thanks anyways. your response was helpful.